React Native Crash error on Google Play Console "com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException"
I recently upgraded my React Native App's targetSDKVersion to 34 with the following steps. I tested these changes after creating the aab file. I recently uploaded the changes to production. But I've got multiple crash & ANR reports in my google play console. They report that the app keeps crashing in multiple devices. I've tested it on a few devices and it's working ok but the crash report suggests that the majority of the crashes are on devices with API 34 and some other older APIs as well. And the stack trace is as follows
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException
Exception com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException:
  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException (ExceptionsManagerModule.java:72)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
  at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:263)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)

Not sure how I should proceed.
